# Customize system fonts with size and attributes for iOS

Tags: ios, ios9, foundation, uifont

In my app I need to support iOS since iOS 7. As you know iOS 9 uses new system font "San-Francisco".
Is it possible some how to use system font (to make native font for operation system) with setting size and attributes like `Light`, `Medium`, `Bold`, `Italic`, etc?

I found only one solution to hard code font name as for iOS 9 use "San-Francisco" and for less use "HelveticaNueue".

Maybe some one know a better solution.